# Django admin do not recognize superuser

Tags: django-models, django-admin

so, in my project django, I have:

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

after creating a superuser and trying to login in django, I see the error:
[image]

same will happen trying to login into my site, after using a view to login, I can see "USER DOES NOT EXIST" in admin login

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are setting 'is_active' to False as default, while it shall be True